# Dell loading symbol freezing on screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, dell

So I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside with Windows 10 in my Dell G3 3590. I had the problem with linux freezing before boot and I solved it by updating the grub to mode nomodeset. However, there's this loading symbol from the Dell loading screen that keeps frozen on the screen. When I print the screen the symbol doesn't appear in the print, so I photographed it. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLnEM.jpg) I have already activate the proprietary driver from Nvidia and also tested version 435 and 440. I tryed, also, a solution from the Askubuntu to erase on the grub the "quiet splash" line, leaving only GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=. This really solved the problem, the system booted without the symbol, however this broke it, the applications started to crash and later I wasn't able to boot it anymore. So, what else i could do?

Edit: I was told in NvidiaDeveloper forum that the 430 driver is outdated and incompatible with a 5.4 kernel. So, I'll have to use the 440, which gives me the problem above.

PC:

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with 4GB GDDR5 graphics memory

8GB 2x4GB DDR4 2666MHz

9th Generation Intel Core i5-9300H (8MB Cache, up to 4.1 GHz, 4 cores)

Comment: You should be using Nvidia 430.09, and can be downloaded at https://www.geforce.com/drivers

Comment: Thank you. I uninstalled the driver using "sudo apt-get purge nvidia*" and "sudo apt-get autoremove", it made the loading symbol disappears. however I'm not being able to install the driver 430.09, it gives me the error "An error occurred while performing the step: "Building kernelmodules". See /var/log/nvidia-installer.log for details." I have already updated the linux-headers with "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic" and checked for the GCC version (9.3.0). Any ideas?

Comment: Did you review `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log`? You're probably missing `dkms` or `build-essential`. Report back.

Comment: I'm not sure what i'm looking for in the log. However, the error starts with 

"In file included from /tmp/selfgz13684/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.09/kernel/nvidia/nv-instance.c:13:
   /tmp/selfgz13684/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.09/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1593:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
    1593 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)"

Comment: Paste the log at paste.ubuntu.com and let me look at it.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8rm2H67ZsR/ Tks

Comment: It may be that Nvidia 430.09 is not compatible with 20.04. I'd contact Nvidia support for more help.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I sad, the Nvidia Driver 430.09 is not compatible with Kernel 5.4. Than, after cleaning the driver with "sudo apt-get purge nvidia*" and "sudo apt-get autoremove" I reinstalled the driver 440 and now the loading symbol doesn't freeze anymore. I'm not sure what I did, but I solved it.

Edit: Actually, I should say that even with 430.09 installed, I couldn't boot without nomodeset parameter on grub. And this breaks the audio driver. Looks like there is some kind of incompatibility between new Dell notebooks and Ubuntu versions newer than 18.04. I returned to the 18.04 version, and now It's working pretty good.